# Issue while running executable jar : ClassNotFoundException coming

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, packaging

I created a jar using Maven install and when i ran the jar using command `java -jar MyJar.jar`  it gave me the exception. Below is the stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I had all dependencies in my pom.xml and i successfully ran the main class as standalone application.

Then I extracted the contents of jar and I was surprised to see there were no dependency jars in it though Manifest file has all the jars in classpath.
Below is the Manifest file generated:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Anand Jain
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_38
Main-Class: com.hcentive.simulator.cms.beq.response.util.Test
Class-Path: spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.j
 ar spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar spring-c
 ontext-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar spring-a
 sm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar cglib-nodep-2.2.jar hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.
 Final.jar spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar spring-bat
 ch-core-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar xstream-1.3.jar xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar jettiso
 n-1.1.jar spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar commons-beanu
 tils-1.8.3.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.j
 ar antlr-2.7.6.jar commons-collections-3.1.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar xml-ap
 is-1.0.b2.jar jta-1.1.jar slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar 
 commons-pool-1.3.jar commons-io-1.3.2.jar commons-lang-2.5.jar hsqldb
 -1.8.0.7.jar aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar log4j-1.2.14
 .jar
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are including the `class-path` element in the Jar's manifest file?

Comment: yes, including that i have mentioned this above

Comment: *"I extracted the contents of jar and I was surprised to see there were no dependency jars in it"*  No.  For a Java application deployment, we typically do not use the 'jar-in-jar' technique that you are referring to, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Andrew - pasted the manifest file

Comment: Can you please suggest how should I approach now?? It's kind of urgent

Comment: Thanks for posting that content.  Are you certain that the manifest ends with a single blank line?  An old behavior that Sun swore was not a bug demanded that a manifest be ended with a blank line to be properly parsed.  Is Maven generating it?  If so, my gut feeling would be to trust the integrity/validity of it.

Comment: *"It's kind of urgent"*  'too localized - a specific moment in time'.  :(

Comment: @Anand Make sure that the dependent Jars are deployed along with the executable Jar.  Based on the manifest, they should reside within the same context as the executable Jar

Answer (score 2):

To build a jar containing all dependencies using maven, you can add...

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.example.MyMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You should also ensure that the scope is set correctly for each dependency.

Comment: Should i run it as Maven install??

Comment: When I ran it as Maven install..it generated two jars--one normal and one jar with depenedency..i want only single jar..

Comment: @JayTee I was under the impression that Java wasn't capable of loading Jar dependencies from within another Jar?  Has this changed recently (cause if it has, I'd be very excited)

Comment: You only need the one marked 'with-dependancies', it will still generate the normal jar without the dependancies also which you can ignore. You should be able to java -jar foo-with-dependancies.jar etc.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I don't know if this is a change, but it certainly works now.

Answer (score -2):

java -classpath jar1;jar2;jar3;jar4;xml1;xml2;....; jar ExceutableJar.jar

I believe it might be having a lot of jar file

I recommend you you to copy the entire command in to a notepad file and save it as batch (.bat) or shell script (.sh) in case of Unix

So that , you can run the jar easily with one file, instead of repeating the command

Comment: not a better solution as I need to handover this jar to QA team for testing..they should not be bothered about any external jars..Isn't there any way to do that automatically without need to give it explicitly on the command path??

Comment: `-cp` is ignored when `-jar` is specified.  Using `-jar` the JVM relies on the manifest in the main jar to specify the class-path.

Comment: -jar ignored?? Blah blah?? Please explain